# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 when using valid json

Tags: python, json, watchdog

I have been using watchdogs and json for my script where I watch for a file to be created and a json to read the file that has been created. The script is as easy as:

```
import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers
import json

def on_created(self, event):

    with open(event.src_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
        data = json.load(f)


def main(self):
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    observer.schedule(NotificationsEvent(), path=os.path.split(self.notificationFlag)[0], recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Basically when there is a new file created with a path of json. Read it and then load is as json and it is working very well but sometimes it throws me an error saying:

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

When I check the print for `f.read()` that returns me:

```
{
    "delay": 0,
    "image": "https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CK9388_484",
    "keyword": false,
    "link": "https://www.nike.com/se/t/traningssko-metcon-6-78352H/CK9388-484",
    "name": "NIKE METCON 6",
    "price": "1337",
    "shortcut": [
        "[Checkout](https://www.nike.com/se/cart)"
    ],
    "sizes": [],
    "sku": "CK9388-100",
    "store": "Nike",
    "text": "New!",
    "webhook": "nike"
}
```

which I have used https://jsonlint.com/ to see if it is valid and it is valid and yet I do get the error sometimes. Which is 1 out of 50 times I do get it. I can't reproduce the error again and it happens very rarely but yet it does happend.

I have no idea and I am losing my mind of what it could be for issue that causing it :(

Appreciate all kind of help!

Comment: The problem may be that your script is running too quickly after the file is created. The writer hasn't had a chance to fill in the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.read()` is reading the entire file, so there's nothing left for `json.load()` to read.

You should read into a variable then use `json.loads()`..

```
def on_created(self, event):

    with open(event.src_path, 'r') as f:
        js = f.read()
        print(js)
        data = json.loads(js)
```

or you can rewind the file between them.

```
def on_created(self, event):

    with open(event.src_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
        f.seek(0)
        data = json.load(f)
```

If you were getting the error without the `print(f.read())` line, then the problem is that your code is running before the writer finishes writing the file.

There isn't really a reliable way to tell when the writer is finished writing the file. The best solution is to have it create the file atomically. It should write the data to a different file, then rename the file to the one that your code is watching for.

You could use a loop with `try/except`

```
def on_created(self, event):
    for _ in range(5): // limit the number of retries
        try:
            with open(event.src_path, 'r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            break
        except JsonDecodeError:
            print("JSON load error, retrying")
            os.sleep(1) // allow time for writer to finish
```

Comment: Alright! I will give this a go aswell :) Thanks! As I mentioned. its super hard to reproduce the error so it can take a while if I get any issue at all using this. but I assume this should be the problem. If not, any suggestion on what else it oculd be?

Comment: Were you getting the error without the `print()`? Then it's probably what I said in my comment.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how to address the problem of trying to read the file before the writer is finished.

Comment: Yes I did get error for JsonDecodeError without the `print` previously. :(

Comment: I believe you might be right about the writing part but then I shouldnt be able to see the JSON format when I did a print before. Because when I had print then I could see that the json was valid and seemed good but as you mentioned. I did not do the seek(0) after the print but I will try give it a go and see if this way works :)

Comment: There are two problems. If you use `print()`, `json.load()` doesn't have anything to load. And in either case the function might run too soon.

Comment: Is there any point to do a try except for JsonDecodeError to retry opening the file?

Comment: That's a good idea. For ordinary files there's no way to know when the writer is done, but for JSON we can tell because valid JSON means it's complete. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! I will try give this a go and see how it will end up! :) Thanks for the ideas! I will update if any issue appears.